# Order of instructions in shell script

Tags: shell, background-process

I have this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "alpha"

finish()
{
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
}
trap finish EXIT

echo "bravo"

cd /non/existent/path
# cd /non/existent/path && gitk &

echo "charlie"
```

When run, this gives the following output as expected:

```
alpha
bravo
./test.sh: 13: cd: can't cd to /non/existent/path
charlie
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

But then, if I uncomment the line containing the `gitk` call (i.e. line 14), I get this output:

```
alpha
bravo
./test.sh: 13: cd: can't cd to /non/existent/path
charlie
--------------------------------------------------------------
./test.sh: 14: cd: can't cd to /non/existent/path
```

Notice how the line with the dashes is no longer at the end. Any idea why this happens?

I also noticed that if I remove the ampersand at the end of that line, the order is once again as I'd expect. So starting gitk as a background process clearly has an impact, but I don't know how exactly.

Finally, is it possible to modify the script such that I can continue to start gitk as a background process but still have the line with the dashes appear at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior is as expected since You spawn a child process via &. If you wanna Your trap function to be executed after just add `wait` in end of Your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "alpha"

finish()
{
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
}
trap finish EXIT

echo "bravo"

cd /non/existent/path
cd /non/existent/path && gitk &

echo "charlie"
wait
```

That will wait on all child processes to be completed and then exits (call trap finish). Output:

```
$ ./gautam.sh
alpha
bravo
./gautam.sh: line 13: cd: /non/existent/path: No such file or directory
charlie
./gautam.sh: line 14: cd: /non/existent/path: No such file or directory
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, uncommenting the line `cd /non/existent/path && gitk &` will cause it to run in background - the `cd` command and, after it runs successfully, the `gitk` command. As the `cd` command is not successful, because the path does not exist, then `gitk` command will not be performed. If you want it to be performed independently from the previous command split them with `;` instead of `&&`

As it runs in background, the scripts continues to the print stage and only when the cpu process commutes to the one you ran in background it will be performed - it may be 10 lines after it is launched, or 5 lines, or 3 lines... there is no right moment for it to be run, so the behaviour you see is normal. Removing the `&` will make it run sequencially in the script.

To start `gitk` as background process and have that line appearing in the end, you can do some `sleep` after gitk instantiation, but as it is it will always return an error of `cd` and `gitk` will not run due to the `&&` operator.